# Drop file onto .jar and pass filename to main()

Tags: java, jar, arguments

I'd like to drop a file onto my jar and have the filename passed on to my main method as argument.
I'm on OSX.
How can I do that?

Comment: What platform? Linux? Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app. is deployed using [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml), a file association can be declared.  Double click any file of that type and the path of the file is supplied to the main(String[]).

BTW - here is a [demo. of the JNLP file API](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  Note well the 2nd bug report, which would mean a minimum version of 1.6.0_10+ in order not to **delete** a file dropped on the application's icon.

Comment: Thank u so far! What about a GUI with a window that files can be dropped onto instead of onto the icon?

Comment: If the 'GUI' you refer to is the Java application, look into the AWT based D'n'D package (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/package-summary.html).  If not, you will need to explain further ( and I will be outside my area of expertise ;).

Answer (score 2):

To do this on OSX you might have to create an application bundle from your .jar. This process is documented pretty well at the [Apple Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001885-SW1) (scroll down to "Mac OS X Application Bundles"). You can build a Java app which blends really well into the OSX desktop if you follow what they present there, and it's pretty easy.